# Question about a functor related to projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory

If $V$ is a vector space over $k$, then the classical way of defining $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is as $(V\backslash\{0\})/k^\times$. When generalizing this notion to schemes, and in particular if we wish to view projective space as a functor, then this point of view is somewhat abandoned (although of course is always "in the background").

I was wondering, if $R$ is a fixed ring and $M$ is a fixed (finitely generated) $R$-module, what can be said about the functor that takes an $R$-algebra $S$ and sends it to $((M\otimes_{R}S)\backslash\{0\})/S^\times$?

Here the quotient is taken to mean the orbit space of the natural action of $S^\times$ and so the functor can be seen as going from the category of $R$-algebras to the category of sets.

Comment: This is not even functorial. For example, you if $M=R$ then this is the functor $S\mapsto (S-\{0\})/S^\times$. What even this is the map $(\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})/\mathbb{Z}^\times\to (\mathbb{F}_3-\{0\})/\mathbb{F}_3^\times)$ induced from the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{F}_3?$ What you really want is, at least in the free case, something like the presheaf quotient of $\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\}$ by $\mathbb{G}_m$. In particular, $\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\}$ has $R$-points the set of tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that the ideal generated by the $a_i$ in $R$ is the unit ideal. In short, being zero isn't functorial

Comment: being a unit is. If you then want to look at the presheaf quotient $(\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\})/\mathbb{G}_m$ it is, as you'd expect, a presheaf but not a sheaf (e.g. with respect to the fppf topology). Its sheafification is $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I might add that this question arose from a problem I'm working on where the function $S\mapsto((M\otimes_{R}S)\backslash\{0\})/S^\times$ arose naturally. It came out so cleanly that I wrongly assumed it to be a functor and assumed it had probably been studied before. I'm glad the problem has led to such a fruitful discussion below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This is mostly just elaborating on what Alex said in the comments.)

This question gets at one of the more subtle things about algebraic geometry if you start (like I do) from the functor-of-points POV, which is that "deleting a point" (or more generally a closed subscheme) from a scheme is a really wacky operation to perform and it's surprising that we can perform it! (**Edit:** But see the discussion in the comments, I'm happier now.)

As Alex says in the comments, this issue already appears for $\mathbb{A}^1$ when we ask, functorially, what "$\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$" could possibly actually mean. $\mathbb{A}^1$ itself is very easy to define: its functor of points is just $\mathbb{A}^1(R) = R$. The most naive definition of $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ would then be that its functor of points sends $R$ to $R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and as Alex says in the comments this fails to even be a functor because morphisms $f : R \to S$ can send nonzero elements to zero elements. Now one can try to rescue the definition by asking: what can we do that's like taking "nonzero elements" but is guaranteed to be functorial?

The answer is the following: an element $r \in R$ is guaranteed to remain nonzero after applying every nonzero morphism $f : R \to S$ iff it avoids every proper ideal iff it's a unit. So we define $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ to be the functor sending $R$ to $R^{\times}$ and now this is even representable by affine scheme, and so a Zariski sheaf etc. and everyone is happy. But I want to emphasize that from the functor-of-points POV it's not entirely obvious that this operation should be called "deleting a point"!

Similarly we can reproduce this discussion for $\mathbb{A}^2$ and ask ourselves what "$\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$" ought to mean. Again $R \mapsto R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is not a functor and again we can ask: which pairs of elements $(r_1, r_2) \in R^2$ are guaranteed to remain nonzero after applying every nonzero morphism? The answer is precisely the pairs which are not both contained in any proper ideal, or equivalently the pairs which generate the unit ideal. So this is how we define $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and more generally $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

---

Now, what can we say about projective spaces from here?

We'd like the presheaf quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ by scaling to have something to do with $\mathbb{P}^1$. This quotient identifies two pairs $(r_1, r_2) \sim (r_1', r_2')$ iff they generate the same $R$-submodule of $R^2$ and so can be thought of as describing lines in $R^2$; more formally you can show that the maps $R \to R^2$ arising in this way are precisely the inclusions of direct summands.

This is a perfectly fine presheaf, but it's no longer a (Zariski, for example) sheaf. It classifies trivial rank $1$ direct summands of the rank $2$ trivial vector bundle, and in general it's possible to glue these together over a Zariski cover to obtain a nontrivial line bundle. So we can sheafify, and I *think* it should be true that the Zariski sheafification is already the correct $\mathbb{P}^1$ (classifying rank $1$ direct summands, not necessarily trivial).

Comment: It is true that if one sheafifies the presheaf quotient $(\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\})/\mathbb{G}_m$ for the *big* Zariski site then one gets $\mathbb{P}^n$. The reason that Zariski sheafification is enough here is related to the non-trivial fact that quasi-coherents in the fppf, etale,... topologies are actually just quasi-coherents in the Zariski topology. More explicitly, the fact that

$$H^1_\text{Zar}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)=H^1_\text{fppf}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)=H^1_\text{et}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$$

is what secretly saves us from needing to sheafify in a more heavy-duty category.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, Alex. Unrelated, but after thinking about it maybe "deleting a point" is less wacky than I thought. We can think of it as asking for a complement in the following sense: say that a subobject (monomorphism) $X \hookrightarrow Y$ has a *complement* $X' \hookrightarrow Y$ if $X$ and $X'$ are disjoint in the sense that their intersection is the initial object, and $X'$ is universal with respect to this property. Then it's meaningful to ask what the complement of $\{ 0 \}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$ is at the level of functors of points. Hmm...

Comment: I would guess that this definition is not well-defined in general. For example, what is the complement of $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$? I would guess it doesn't exist, essentially because the closed subset $\{0\}$ can be given the scheme structure $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^n))$ for any $n$ and there is no 'largest' such one, which is I think what you are asking for.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe it seems even less wacky zoomed further out: sheaves are a topos, so subobjects are a Heyting algebra. This isn’t really any different than what you said but gives it more of an “of course” quality for me. The question becomes whether the complement is a scheme, not whether it exists at all. That said, I was also initially nodding along with the claim that deleting a point feels like a creepy thing to do to a sheaf!

Comment: @Alex: to be clear I'm not expecting complements to exist in general; universal objects don't exist in general, but at least when they exist they're unique by the universal property and the uniqueness is what I really wanted to pin down here. I'm also thinking of complements taken in, say, Zariski sheaves, not schemes necessarily. I think the argument I gave above should end up saying that $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the complement of $\{ 0 \}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$, in Zariski sheaves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's fine, but then since complementation seems to be symmetric the fact that $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$'s complement is not $\{0\}$ should imply that the complement of $\{0\}$ is not $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$. Perhaps the complement in yoru definition captures something closer to the formal complement. Like is the complement of $\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ equal to the locally ringed space given by $\mathrm{Spf}(k[[x]])$?

Comment: @Alex: the definition I gave doesn't imply that complements are symmetric and they won't be in general, e.g. they aren't in Heyting algebras (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocomplement). In other words "double negation" is generally nontrivial.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see. Just to point out, I'm pretty sure that with your definition the complement of the open subscheme $U$ of a scheme $X$ is the Zariski sheaf represented by the completion of $X$ along the complement $Z$ of $U$.

Comment: That's a nice answer if that's what it ends up being! Isn't this one of the constructions that shows up in the Beauville-Laszlo theorem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes--if you want to glue a vector bundle over $X-\{p\}$ and $\{p\}$ you need agreeance on a formal neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You can verify this by thinking functorially, but if you think about it like I mentioned above it's quite intuitive. The complement of $\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ should intuitively be the closed subscheme $\{0\}$. But, which one? Well, the closed subscheme structures are $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^n))$ and we want the 'largest one', so taking the colimit gives the locally ringed space $\mathrm{Spf}(k[[x]])$. Verifying it functorially is just the realization that $\mathrm{Spf}(k[[x]])$ represents the functor on scheme which takes $R$ to the nilpotents in $R$. One can then think that if

Comment: you have a map to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ whose fiber product with $\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ is trivial, then thinking prime by prime one has that $x$ must map into something in the intersection of all prime ideals of $R$ which is $\mathrm{Nil}(R)$.

Comment: Oh, this is very nice! It's the same sort of argument as above: you want to know which elements $r \in R$ are not only not units but never map to units under nonzero morphisms $f : R \to S$. We can restrict our attention to the case that $S$ is a field. If $P$ is any prime ideal not containing $r$ then $r$ maps to a unit in $\text{Frac}(R/P)$, so $r$ must lie in every prime ideal, hence must be nilpotent, and of course nilpotents never map to units and are functorial as desired. Very cool! So we get an "abstract reason" to take completions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan We should cowrite a blog post about it :P

Comment: Happy for you to write it and cite this discussion! You can probably give details about checking which things are sheaves in which topologies much better.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, but I don't know what a category is. I am semi-serious though. If you ever wanna cowrite a blogpost or something, that could be fun. Let me know!

Comment: What a fantastic and enlightening discussion! Very interesting...